# is it less efficient to reference an instance variable array element multiple times than a local variable?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, performance, variables, instance-variables

If I do:

```
foos[i] = [[Foo alloc] init];
foos[i].prop = @"bar";
[foos[i] baz];
```

...  Is that less efficient than:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
foo.prop = @"bar";
[foo baz];
foos[i] = foo;
```

or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is a simple a C array (`Foo * array[11];`), then it will not have significant performance impact.

If your array is an `NSMutableArray` (or another subscriptable NS-type), then it will have to call the method's implementation repeatedly (which uses short circuited dispatch), so that will introduce some overhead. Although some would consider it a micro-optimization. In this case, the compiler cannot **know** what the implementation returns, so it cannot omit the calls.

---

Here are basic wall clock time results:

> MRC:
>
> > NSArray: 27 seconds
> >
> > C Array: 18 seconds
>
> ARC:
>
> > NSArray: 31 seconds
> >
> > C Array: 18 seconds

and the program (which you can perform the obvious ARC changes to to test ARC):

```
const int NIter = 10000;

__attribute__((noinline)) void fn1() {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableArray * foos = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NIter; ++idx) {
      NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString new];
      foos[0] = str;
      [foos[0] length];
      [foos removeAllObjects];
      [str release];
    }
  }
}

__attribute__((noinline)) void fn2() {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableString * foos[1];
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NIter; ++idx) {
      foos[0] = [NSMutableString new];
      [foos[0] length];
      [foos[0] release];
      foos[0] = 0;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < NIter; ++idx) {
    if (UseNSArray) {
      fn1();
    }
    else {
      fn2();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They're not equivalent, but they are sufficiently close that an optimizing compiler might generate exactly the same binary code.

Even if it doesn't, you'll struggle to measure the difference (unless `foos` is a C++ class with an extremely expensive `operator[]`). Until a profiler says otherwise — optimizing this code is premature.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, unless the compiler optimizes it away. Whether it is *significantly* less efficient is another matter, which depends on what else your code is doing. Worrying about mico-optimizations like this is generally futile unless you already have evidence of an efficiency problem in this vicinity.